# 'Undefined References' Error during OpenGL Pgm Compiling (freeglut3)

Tags: opengl

I tried to run an openGL pgm in my Ubuntu 14.04 and i have freeglut3 and dev installed. But it returns some 'Undefined References' to all the functions that i have used in my pgm.

```
rahul@rahul-System-Product-Name:~$ g++ -lGL -lGLU -lglut nrs1.c
/tmp/ccIsCRgh.o: In function `myInit()':
nrs1.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `glPointSize'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `glOrtho'
nrs1.c:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `gluLookAt'
nrs1.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
nrs1.c:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
/tmp/ccIsCRgh.o: In function `triangle(float*, float*, float*)':
nrs1.c:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `glVertex3fv'
nrs1.c:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `glVertex3fv'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `glVertex3fv'
/tmp/ccIsCRgh.o: In function `tetra(float*, float*, float*, float*)':
nrs1.c:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `glColor3fv'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `glColor3fv'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `glColor3fv'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `glColor3fv'
/tmp/ccIsCRgh.o: In function `display()':
nrs1.c:(.text+0x4cb): undefined reference to `glClear'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x4d7): undefined reference to `glBegin'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x50e): undefined reference to `glEnd'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x513): undefined reference to `glFlush'
/tmp/ccIsCRgh.o: In function `main':
nrs1.c:(.text+0x530): undefined reference to `glutInit'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x53c): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x550): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x564): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x570): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x57c): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x588): undefined reference to `glEnable'
nrs1.c:(.text+0x592): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
```

Please suggest solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the link order: `g++ nrs1.c -lglut -lGLU -lGL`